# Removed splash screen still appears in my app

Tags: iphone

please i make a project under xcode with a splash screen (Default.png). Then, i created new project and i didn't put on it a splash screen, but when i execute it i see this Default.png still appear which i don't want, i deleted the old project to make sure but it still there, help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove your app use the Organizer (Window > Organizer). Then select your device, then your app and press the minus button. You could also delete your app from the device in the conventional way: hold icon for few seconds, then click X after it starts to shake.

To clean use Build > Clean (or Product > Clean on Xcode 4).

Comment: Does that mean if the app is already in the app store, there's no way to remove the splash screen in future builds? (well I guess you can replace Default.png with a black image...)

Answer (score 3):

Try to clean the project, and remove the app from your device. If a `Default.png` is still either in the `build` directory, or in the app directory on the device, it will appear. Simply removing a file from XCode is not enough to make it disappear while developing.

Comment: Thx for your answer, but how can i clean my project and remove the app from my device ??

Comment: Removing your app: press and hold icon, then click X. Cleaning in xcode: Build / Clean.